# How do I add a button to a Webview on Android?

Tags: android, webview

I am generating a webview programmatically I would like to add a button over the webview. I am able to add a normal button, but that comes before the webview, not over it.

Is there a way that I can add the button over the webview?

Comment: hii,,,, you can try to have a webview and button in relative layout(parent layout) programatically..And align the button the desired position with respect to webview...

Comment: This I have already tried this gets the button and webview side by side or one after another. I want the button to be over the webview

Comment: If you post your XML layout file or your lines for programmatically attempting to add the button, someone will be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the button on top of a WebView by using a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

First add the WebView to the Layout, then the Button and adjust the gravity of the Button so that it sits where you want it to.

Comment: Where can we change the gravity?

Answer (score 2):

> Use like this ...

```
      <FrameLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="500dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/main_web "
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

                 <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                  ></ImageButton>
        </FrameLayout>
```